# On complex vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

I am pretty new to complex vector spaces and do not understand match. Can someone help me with this?

I am given a vector space over $\mathbb{C}\ \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3 = \{(z_1,z_2,z_3)\,|\,z_1,z_2,z_3 \in\mathbb{C}\}$, and are asked to find the dimension, the basis of $\mathbb{C}^3$ and show that $W = \{(z_1,z_2,z_3)\in\mathbb{C}^3\,|\,z_1 + iz_2 −z_3 = 0\}$ is a complex subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$. So far I know that $\dim(\mathbb{C}^3)=3$ but I am not sure how to do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the dimension of $\Bbb C$ *over itself* is $1$. The dimension of $\Bbb C^3$ is 3 (work like you would for $\Bbb R^3$).

For your second question, you can simply see that $z_1 = z_3 - iz_2\implies W = \{(z_3 - iz_2,\ z_2,\ z_3)\ |\ z_2,\ z_3 \in {\Bbb C}\} = \{z_3(1, 0, 1)+z_2(-i, 1, 0)\ |z_2,\ z_3 \in {\Bbb C} \}$)